# how search for an item in a datagrid view

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am having a problem while searching for an item in datagridview
here is my code but whenever i search for an item which already exist in the database, it is telling not found

```
If txtfirstname.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please enter first name!")
Else
    Dim totalrow As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
    Dim rowin As Integer
    Dim flag As Boolean = False
    Dim sear As String = CStr(txtfirstname.Text)

    For rowin = 0 To totalrow
        Dim id As String = DataGridView1.Item(0, rowin).Value

        If sear = id Then
            DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
            DataGridView1.Rows(rowin).Selected = True
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Item(0, rowin)

            flag = True
            Exit Sub
        Else
            flag = False
        End If

    Next rowin

    If flag = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Firstname " & txtfirstname.Text & " is not found in database.", "Search Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If

End If
```

Comment: Some things seem a little odd: Why should `totalrow` be `DataGridView1.RowCount - 2`? Wouldn't it be simpler to make a dedicated query to the database to check if a record exists instead of looping over all (worst case) records in the dataset?

Comment: Well it could be that the *firstname* you are looking for is actually in the very last record of your grid and since you make your `For` loop iterate over **all records but the very last** (RowCount - 2) you'll never find it. Try `Dim totalrow As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1`.

Comment: So how did it turn out? Did you try as I suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

By setting

```
Dim totalrow As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
```

you are always missing the last record in your dataset.

Try

```
Dim totalrow As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
```

to set the upper bound value of your `For` loop.